# Repositories, mappers, and how to load objects and their relations

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm using C++ (with the Qt library) to make a simple domain modeled application. I am writing my own O/R mapping classes. As this application will grow in the future I'm trying to keep a clean codebase with clearly separated layers.

The problem I am having is when and where to load aggregate roots that are referenced in an object in another module. (I am using Eric Evans' use of the word "module" here, from the DDD book.)

I currently have a simple object called `Client` that sits in the `ClientModule` module. In the `PermitModule` I have a `Permit` object. (*the reality is more complex but for brevity I'll stick to those two objects, since they are the aggregate roots*) The `Permit` object has a reference to a `Client` as `applicant`. This is my domain model.

From the bottom up, I have an **Infrastructure Layer** that contains O/R mapping classes and concrete implementations of `Repository` objects. So I would have a `ClientMapper`, `ClientRepositoryDb`, `PermitMapper`, and `PermitRepositoryDb` classes here.

Next is the **Domain Layer** that contains the domain model (`Client` and `Permit` classes) plus the repository interfaces `ClientRepository` and `PermitRepository`.

Above that I have an **Application Layer** and then a **Presentation Layer** but those don't matter in this example.

**My question** is should the relationship between `Permit` and `Client` be loaded in the `PermitMapper` class or in the `PermitRepository` class. Or is there some other way of doing it?

This goes not only for loading objects but also for saving them and removing them.

Comment: Hi! I'm currently facing the exact same issue. How did your approach end up look like and what exactly did you do? How does your Domain-Object get the data?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with the approach that my Mapper classes load themselves fully.

I'm not a Java developer but I wonder how Hibernate (et al) does it?